# C++ fast floor templates: C4430 Error with Visual Studio on Windows

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I am attempting to create a template for fast floors.

And I have the following start of a template, but I am receiving an error when compiling under Windows related to the usage of IN and OUT within my code. Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

```
template<typename IN, typename OUT>
class FastConversion {
    public:
        FastConversion() {
            // empty
        }

        // rounds to the next lowest whole number
        //     1.5 -->  1.0
        //    -1.5 --> -2.0
        inline OUT floor(const IN& x) {
            OUT output = 0;
            // slowest version
            #if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__linux__) || defined(WIN64)
                output = static_cast<OUT>(std::floor(static_cast<double>(x)));
            #elif defined(WIN32)
                __asm {
                    fld x;
                    fadd st, st(0);
                    fadd negOneHalf;
                    fistp i;
                    sar i, 1;
                };
            #else
                output = static_cast<OUT>(std::floor(static_cast<double>(x)));
            #endif
            return output;
        }
};
```

With an invocation as:

```
inline i32 fastFloor(f64 x) {
    FastConversion<f64, i32> f;
    i32 floored = f.floor(x);
    return floored;
}
```

Note:  i32 and f64 are as expected (int and double).  I'm running a 32-bit compile on a 64-bit machine.  I'm using C++-11.  I have a CMake file as well as a vcxproj file.

And the following error:

```
FastConversion.h(40): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

I can seem to compile fine with clang on a mac, but when I attempt the same with Visual Studio, I end up with the error above.

Thanks!

Comment: There are two undefined variables in class definition: `negOneHalf` and `i`. When I defined these and `typedef int i32; typedef double f64;` your code compiled without errors on VC++ 2010.

Comment: Just a side question, what makes this conversion fast?

Comment: It compiles fine on VS2013 and VS2010 using just `#include <cmath>` and search/replacing `i32` with `int` and `f64` with `double`. That leads me to suspect that `IN` and `OUT` are clashing with some preprocessor definition somewhere. Does it work for you if you rename the template types to `T` and `U` for example?

Comment: @AndyBrown: It must have been a clash in naming.  T/U works just fine.  Thanks!  I'll wait a bit if you want to add an answer.  :D

Comment: Thanks Brian, I copied the comment to an answer so it's easier to find for googlers in the future.

Comment: @user1767754 this is still a WIP, and I intend to optimize with SSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It compiles fine on VS2013 and VS2010 using just `#include <cmath>` and ***search/replacing i32*** with ***int*** and ***f64*** with ***double***. That leads me to suspect that ***IN*** and ***OUT*** are clashing with some preprocessor definition somewhere. Does it work for you if you rename the template types to `T` and `U` for example?